# HTML5 Video / Jquery - current.Time Issue

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I'm working on a project where I need to jump to different times in a single video all while looping with in designated sections.

For example: Video A is divided into two parts, Part One (1-10 seconds) and Part Two (11 -20 seconds). Initially, Part One loops until a button is pressed, at which point current time will jump to Part Two which will loop within Part Two.

My code works up until the point where the button is pressed. The error seems to be related to the use of the .bind() function but I'm not sure. This is just an exerpt up until the point the error occurs.

```
$("#first").bind("timeupdate", function () {
    if (this.currentTime > 10) this.currentTime = 0;
});



$('#hit').on('click', function () {

    $("#first").bind("timeupdate", function () {
        this.currentTime = 11;

    if (this.currentTime > 20) this.currentTime = 11;
});


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jcLRe/17/

After looking at similiar articles, it seems this is a common issue. Appreciate any help.

-Thanks!

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/jcLRe/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `$("#first")` is already bind in `this.currentTime > 10`. So when you clicked the "Hit" button and this.currentTime = 11, it will turn to 0 again because of the first bind. Muse's answer is correct. And if you want to toggle the Hit button to play from zero again. Just change the `section = 2` to

```
if(section == 1) 
        section = 2;
    else 
        section = 1;
```